# how may I edit an entry?

Tags: word-usage

I've tried to offer you an answer about the use of "closet" and "wardrobe" in the United States, but cannot find a way to do that.  In Colonial times, in the United States, homes and buildings were taxed by the number of rooms they had.  Closets were counted as rooms.  So, widespread use of wardrobes ensued.  As tax laws changed, the use of wardrobes finally phased out.